# can't create dynamic relocation R_AARCH64_ADD_ABS_LO12_NC against symbol

Tags: c++, machine-learning, static-libraries, ndk-build, mlpack

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

MlPack(branch): [master](https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack)

I am trying to build a program which is dependent on `mlpack` for android. For that I am using ndk-build. To make the library compatible for arm64 architecture, I have used [buildroot environment](https://buildroot.org/) 2020.08.1 to create the sysroot and aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc and aarch64-linux-gnu-g++. I have followed [this](https://community.arm.com/oss-platforms/w/docs/499/build-a-buildroot-user-space) link and set the following menuconfig to do that:

```
    Target options → TargetArchitecture = AArch64 (Little Endian)
    Toolchain → Toolchain type = External
    Toolchain  → Toolchain = Linaro AArch64
    Filesystem images → enable "tar the root file system"
```

Then, in mlpack/build folder I have run the following command:

```
cmake -DDEBUG=OFF -DPROFILE=OFF -DBUILD_MARKDOWN_BINDINGS=OFF -DBUILD_PYTHON_BINDINGS=OFF -DBUILD_GO_BINDINGS=OFF -DBUILD_JULIA_BINDINGS=OFF -DBUILD_R_BINDINGS=OFF -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../board/crosscompile-toolchain.cmake -DBOARD_NAME="RPI4" -DDISABLE_DOWNLOADS=OFF -DTOOLCHAIN_PREFIX=//home/niaz/buildroot-2020.08.1/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu- -DCMAKE_SYSROOT=/home/niaz/buildroot-2020.08.1/output/host/arm64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot ../
```

I followed [this](https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/3160#issuecomment-1060010568) command here for that.

But after I try to compile the following code to `ndk-build`, I get the error:
**hello.hpp**

```cpp
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class hello{
    public:
    string getJniString(string save_model_path);
};
```

**hello.cpp**

```cpp
#include "hello.hpp"
#include "mlpack/core.hpp"
#include "mlpack/methods/random_forest/random_forest.hpp"
#include "mlpack/methods/decision_tree/random_dimension_select.hpp"
#include "mlpack/core/cv/k_fold_cv.hpp"
#include "mlpack/core/cv/metrics/accuracy.hpp"
#include "mlpack/core/cv/metrics/precision.hpp" 
#include "mlpack/core/cv/metrics/recall.hpp"

 
using namespace arma;
using namespace mlpack;
using namespace mlpack::tree;
using namespace mlpack::cv;
using namespace std;

string hello::getJniString(string save_model_path){
    string val = "";
    mat dataset;
    bool loaded = mlpack::data::Load("encoded_food.txt",dataset);
    if (!loaded){
        val = "failed to load";
        return val;
    }
        

    Row<size_t> labels;
    labels = conv_to<Row<size_t>>::from(dataset.row(dataset.n_rows - 1));
    dataset.shed_row(dataset.n_rows - 1);
    const size_t numClasses = 4;
    const size_t minimumLeafSize = 5;
    const size_t numTrees = 10;
    RandomForest<GiniGain, RandomDimensionSelect> rf;
    rf = RandomForest<GiniGain, RandomDimensionSelect>(dataset, labels,
        numClasses, numTrees, minimumLeafSize);

    Row<size_t> predictions;
    rf.Classify(dataset, predictions);
    const size_t correct = arma::accu(predictions == labels);
    val = "Training Accuracy: " + to_string(double(correct) / double(labels.n_elem));
    mlpack::data::Save(save_model_path, "model", rf, false);
    return val;

}
```

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/boost
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/ -lboost_serialization-clang-mt-a64-1_74 -lboost_program_options-clang-mt-a64-1_74 -lmlpack
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -Wl

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -frtti
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fopenmp
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fPIC

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -B/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions 

LOCAL_MODULE = hello-jni-prebuilt
CODE_PATH := .
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/build/include $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = hello.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Application.mk**

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-21
APP_CFLAGS += -Wno-error=format-security
APP_ABI := all
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang++
APP_STL:= c++_static
APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS=true
```

**Error**

```
ld: error: relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 cannot be used against symbol std::runtime_error::~runtime_error(); recompile with -fPIC
>>> defined in /home/niaz/NDK/android-ndk-r23b-linux/android-ndk-r23b/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/../llvm-libc++/libs/arm64-v8a/libc++abi.a(stdlib_stdexcept.o)
>>> referenced by prefixedoutstream.cpp
>>>               prefixedoutstream.cpp.o:(_ZN6mlpack4util17PrefixedOutStream9BaseLogicIbEENSt9enable_ifIXntsrN4arma12is_arma_typeIT_EE5valueEvE4typeERKS6_) in archive /home/niaz/u/new/android-deliverables-24.2/jni/lib/libmlpack.a
```

[image]

I have found in some similar questions that adding `-fPIC -WL -z` as flags should solve this issue. But I do not understand how to add them in Android.mk or Application.mk

Answer (score 1):

Even if I add -fPIC to CFlags the error still occurs. I solve same issue by send `-Bsymbolic` to ld, see more at https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/9933#issuecomment-1029775358

Comment: I later used the source code to build the library. In my case, I had solved the issue by removing the `fPIC` and `frtti` flag. I am not sure why it worked though.